# reCaptchav2 error message: We detected that your site is verifying reCAPTCHA passed solutions less than 50% of the time

Tags: php, recaptcha

I integrated reCaptcha into a test form so we can use reCaptcha to stop bots. After completing all the front-end and server-side code I am amble to test if the user successfully completed the reCatpha - but when I check the reCaptcha admin I see this message:

"We detected that your site is verifying reCAPTCHA passed solutions less than 50% of the time. This could indicate a problem with your integration with reCAPTCHA. Please see our developer site for more information."

What am I doing wrong with my server-side validation. I have checked Stackoverflow and other sites for a PHP solution but nothing fixes the problem.

Here is my code striped down.

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contact | Blah Blah</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $responseErr = "";
    $responseMsg = ""; // for debugging purposes
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        // reCaptcha server side integraton
        $secretKey = "secretkey-blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"; // required
        $responseKey = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]; // required

        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $responseMsg = "<p>The response is: $response</p>"; // for debugging purposes
        $response = json_decode($response);
        if($response->success){

            // recaptcha validates so continue submitting the form.
            $responseErr = '<p><span style="color:green">* reCaptcha verified</span></p>'; // for debugging purposes
        } else {

            // recaptcha doesn't validate so give the user an error message.
            $responseErr = '<p><span style="color:red">* reCaptcha is required</span></p>';
        }
    }
?>

<form class="recaptchaFrom clearfix" method="post">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="medium-12 columns a-left">
        <div class="g-recaptcha m-bottom" data-sitekey="sitekey-blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"></div>    
        <?php echo $responseMsg; // for debugging purposes ?>
        <?php echo $responseErr; ?>             
    </div>
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you see their developer site for more information?

Comment: Yes. I'm "Verifying the user's response" in the first way - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify. BTW, what exactly does "We detected that your site is verifying reCAPTCHA passed solutions less than 50% of the time." mean? When I look at the chart for "Requests passed & failed" I see 20 no captchas 5 passed 1 fail. Does this mean reCaptcha didn't show up? or does 20 no captchas mean the user didn't need to do the fallback puzzle challenge?

Comment: Let me add the $responseMsg that gets spit out when I am debugging: When reCaptcha succeeds I see The response is: { "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2019-03-07T19:42:19Z", "hostname": "localhost" } and when it fails I see The response is: { "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }. Hopefully someone can determine from this is I am truly getting a response from reCaptcha and if maybe the issue I see in the admin is a bug of some sort - a message I can ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same error in reCAPTCHA admin. You did not use isset and also used urlencode functions when passing secret key. Like this, Hope this will solve your problem.

```
if(isset($_POST['captcha']) && !empty( $_POST['captcha'])){
       $response=$_POST['captcha'];
```

}

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secret) .  '&response=' . urlencode($response));
```

Comment: I was missing isset and I should look into urlencode. Here is my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

        // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NfaBfu_ndc
        $responseErr = "";
        $responseMsg = ""; // for debugging purposes
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            // reCaptcha server side integraton
            $secretKey = "blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"; // required
            $responseKey = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]; // required

            $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey";
            $responseFile = file_get_contents($url); // send the $url to the Google reCaptcha server for validation and get a response back
            $responseJSON = json_decode($responseFile); // decode the content of the $response
            $debugSKEY = "SECRET KEY is $secretKey"; // for debugging purposes
            if ($responseKey == null){
                $responseKey = '<span style="color:red">empty</span>';
                $urlresponseKey = $responseKey;
            }
            $debugGREC = "G RECAPTCHA RESPONSE is $responseKey"; // for debugging purposes
            $debugURL = "RECAPTCHA URL is $url" . $urlresponseKey; // for debugging purposes
            $debugFILE = "FILE GET CONTENTS is $responseFile"; // for debugging purposes
            if($responseJSON->success == true){

                // recaptcha validates so continue submitting the form.
                $responseErr = '<p><span style="color:green">* reCaptcha verified</span></p>'; // for debugging purposes
            } else {

                // recaptcha doesn't validate so give the user an error message.
                $responseErr = '<p><span style="color:red">* reCaptcha is required</span></p>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```